# Micronaut and Gradle can't get tests working

Tags: java, gradle, micronaut

I'm new to Micronaut and Gradle and I'm having some issues trying to get a simple controller application setup. I can run the app but the tests do not work. I'm thinking it must be due to my gradle configuration.

All of my classes exist in the same package.

Here is my simple application test:

```
package com.company;

import io.micronaut.runtime.EmbeddedApplication;
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@MicronautTest(packages="com.company")
class ApplicationTest {

  @Inject EmbeddedApplication<?> application;

  @Test
  void testItWorks() {
    Assertions.assertTrue(application.isRunning());
  }
}
```

and my simple application:

```
package com.company;

import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Micronaut.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

I can run the application just fine. But when I try to use the tests I get the following error:

```
Failed to inject value for field [application] of class: com.company.ApplicationTest

Path Taken: ApplicationTest.application
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for field [application] of class: com.company.ApplicationTest

Path Taken: ApplicationTest.application
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1462)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1203)
    at com.company.$ApplicationTestDefinition.injectBean(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.inject(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:339)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doInject(DefaultBeanContext.java:2208)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.inject(DefaultBeanContext.java:789)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.beforeEach(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:303)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.beforeEach(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:112)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:159)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:158)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.runtime.EmbeddedApplication] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2348)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1245)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1441)
    ... 79 more
```

I have a similar error with my controller tests

```
package com.company.controller;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;

@Controller("/")
public class TestController {

  @Get(produces = "text/plain")
  public String index() {
    return "Micronaut Webservice Example for Demo";
  }
}
```

My controller test class:

```
package com.company.controller;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;
import io.micronaut.http.client.RxHttpClient;
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.*;
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@MicronautTest
public class TestControllerTest {

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    RxHttpClient client;

    @Test
    public void testIndex() {
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, client.toBlocking().exchange("/helloController").status());
    }
}
```

Here is the error

```
Error instantiating bean of type  [com.company.controller.TestControllerTest]

Message: Invalid service reference [/] specified to @Client
Path Taken: TestControllerTest.client
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [com.company.controller.TestControllerTest]

Message: Invalid service reference [/] specified to @Client
Path Taken: TestControllerTest.client
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1951)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getScopedBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2450)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2365)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2337)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1245)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1441)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1203)
    at com.company.controller.$TestControllerTestDefinition.injectBean(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.inject(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:339)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doInject(DefaultBeanContext.java:2208)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.inject(DefaultBeanContext.java:789)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.beforeEach(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:303)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.beforeEach(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:112)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$1(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:159)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$5(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:158)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientException: Invalid service reference [/] specified to @Client
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.lambda$null$0(RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:229)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:401)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.lambda$getClient$1(RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:228)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.getClient(RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:191)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.getClient(RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:142)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.resolveClient(RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:384)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.httpClient(RxNettyHttpClientRegistry.java:187)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.$RxNettyHttpClientRegistry$HttpClient0Definition.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.build(AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.java:118)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1911)
    ... 84 more
```

Here is my relevant Gradle configuration:

```
micronaut {
    version("${versions.micronaut}")
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.company.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime:${versions.micronaut}")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation:${versions.micronaut}")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client:${versions.micronaut}")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")
    compile ('io.netty:netty-all:4.0.24.Final')
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:${versions.micronaut}"
    testAnnotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:${versions.micronaut}"
    testImplementation group: 'io.micronaut.test', name: 'micronaut-test-junit5', version:'2.3.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I have attempted to reproduce the problem using your code and I cannot.  Does the problem happen when you run `gradlew test`?

Comment: yes I get the same issue. I'm using IntelliJ. I have annotations processing enabled.

Comment: If you can send a PR to https://github.com/jeffbrown/dboychucktest which demonstrates the problem, I would be happy to take a look.  If it looks like you have uncovered a bug, please report at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues and we will investigate.  I suspect the issue is in your environment, but if you find otherwise please let us know.

Comment: I had the same issue and resolved it by adding this dependency:
`implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty"`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, solved it by adding this dependency:

```
implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty"
```

side-note: I just ran into this problem (again), googled it and landed here - saw my previous comment on the original post made in June, followed my own advice - problem solved.

Comment: This seems to create a timeout exception when this adding this to a project that is nested inside another project which already has netty dependency. But I can't find another solution for it.

Comment: I hate that this works for me and yet I have absolutely no idea why. I see no logical connection between this package and the bean instantiation error I (and the OP) was seeing (not that I even know what the package is meant to do, really, nor how to find out), yet somehow, nonsensically, it fixes things. I hate the amount of incomprehensible magic that happens behind the scenes with Micronaut packages.